# Rails Validation: need to validate all objects in associated collection but each object saves one at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have the following association:

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :budget_components
end

class BudgetComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :budget
end
```

when I save `budget`'s collection of `budget_component` objects a field (we'll call it `revenute_precentage`) in the `budget_component needs to be validated such that all of the`budget`'s`budget_component`'s`revenue_percentage`fields add up to`1.0` (e.g. that all must equal 100% together).

The problem I'm anticipating to happen is that the database might validate one at time or compare the one unsaved record with the saved records and what should be valid, may be invalidated.

Should I add a validator on the `budget` object that validates is `budget_components` or will this just work?

Comment: You could add a before_save callback in your budget.rb

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally add a validator to the `BudgetComponent` model, and pass data through `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, like this:

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :budget_components
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :budget_components
end

class BudgetComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :budget

  validates :your, :attributes,
     presence: { message: "Can't be blank!" }
end
```

This will mean when you pass your params from your form to your model, it will validate each member of the collection individually

You'll have to use [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) to get this working correctly